# Redirect to mobile page in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mobile, user-agent

I'm trying to create a webpage that should automatically detect whether a mobiel version (/mobile(index) or the desktop version (/en/index or /de/index) should be displayed depending on the user's device.

So with lot's of research I accomplished the following htaccess File:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^/?$ /de/index [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

It basically puts the user into the German version of the page when visiting first (that should be changed afterwards) and removes the html-extension from the URL.

Now I wanted to add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|ipad|android|blackberry [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /mobile/index
```

But for some reason it just won't work.

I guess what I'm looking for is some kind of if-else condition (if mobile then mobile/index else de/index).

Anyway I appreaciate any advice you may give me!
Kind regards, chrissik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting that rule before your redirect and exclude it from redirecting:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|ipad|android|blackberry [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /mobile/index

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(iphone|ipad|android|blackberry) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /de/index [R]
```

---

EDIT: You can also add:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iphone|ipad|android|blackberry [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile
RewriteRule ^(de/)?(.+)$ /mobile/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Maybe you can give me some additional help. Now I want the mobile page to be displayed with any link (example: Android devices tries to display page/de/visitor -> should redirect to page/mobile/visitor). If you could help me with that it would be awesome!

Comment: @chrissik see edit, that shoould point you in the right direction

Comment: I've added your edit, but if I call /de/index with user agent 'iOS' e.g. I get a Internal Server Error-message (so that means that something is triggered in your code, but somehow not redirected properly I guess). Any idea on why it wouldn't work? And sorry for replying so late - I had to fix my setup for multiple hours...